# Active Admin displaying without styles

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass, activeadmin, webpacker

Im having some trouble switching from administrate gem to active admin gem. I actually had everything working well, then I went to restart my server due to a config change i made and now, while my active admin panel is still technically working, It is displayed without any styles applied to it just in the default styling the browser applies.

Are there some things I can check to see what is causing this? Im not sure what to check because I am new to active admin and there isn't any apparent error method. I checked back through the docs for setting up active admin and I think I have everything right.

Any help is appreciated!

Possibly of note: I am using webpacker.

Answer (score 0):

The active_admin.scss file had to be moved from vendors/assets/stylesheets to app/assets/stylehseets.

edited for spelling.